# how do i programmatically create folder for application to upload content in it using BOX rest api

Tags: c++, qt, oauth-2.0, blackberry-10, box-api

I want to support box cloud facility my blackberry 10 app,for this i'm using box rest api to implement this functionality. so using [box rest oauth2.0](http://developers.box.com/oauth/) i able to get authorizedcode and then accessToken and RefreshToken but still not able to create a folder of my app to upload content to user's box account. So please suggest me how do i implement this.

Thanks,

Ankur

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include a little of your code.  Otherwise this question won't really help anyone else.

If you've made it through the authentication stage, then you're 99% of the way there.  You can create a folder by doing a POST to https://api.box.com/folders with a JSON payload that provides the name and parent_id of the folder you want to create and the location you want to create it in.

Answer (score 0):

From your code above, it looks like you're trying to send a POST request to https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0

Folder creation requests should actually be POST'd to:
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders

Note, there isn't a 0 there. I understand that it's fairly intuitive to POST to the ID of the parent folder you desire, but this is how we handle this.

Your request body must indicate the parent folder like this:

```
var postData ={"name":"New Folder", "parent":{"id": "0"}};
```

Hope that helps!